# Why is XCU the abbreviation for "Shell and Utilities" and XSH the abbreviation for "System Interfaces"?

Tags: posix, terminology

POSIX is divided into 4 major volumes, and the abbreviations XBD, XSH, XCU and XRAT are used throughtout, respectively standing for "Base Definitions", "Shell and Utilities", "System Interfaces" and "Rationale". For what it's worth, "Shell and Utilities" and "System Interfaces" should be called XSU and XSI instead of XSH and XCU.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The abbreviations are historical: XCU is used for the [“Shell and Utilities”](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/xcu.html) volume (check the URL), which used to be called [Commands and Utilities](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9695969399/toc.pdf); XSH is used for the [“System Interfaces”](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/xsh.html) volume, which used to be called [System Interfaces and Headers](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9695969499/toc.pdf).

(Your question swaps XSH and XCU, but since your title gets them right I imagine that’s inadvertent.)